# Парсинг фотографий с сайта

Tags: python, python-3.x

Возникла проблема с парсингом с сайта http://e-shuushuu.net/?page=1

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {'accept': '*/*',
            'user-agent': ... }

base_url = 'http://e-shuushuu.net/?page=1'

def parse(base_url, headers):
    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(base_url, headers = headers)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs(request.content,'html.parser')
        divs = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'thumb'})
        for div in divs:
            titles = div.find('a', attrs={'class': 'thumb_image'})
            print(titles)
    else:
        print('Error')

parse(base_url,headers)
```

Проблема в том, что при выводе titles выходят лишние элементы страницы .

Comment: Ну правильно твой код все выводит, каждый элемент `a` содержит два ребенка, пустой `span` и `img`, они и выводятся.

Comment: Нельзя это как-то убрать?)

Comment: А тебе нужен сам элемент или все же лишь какая-то информация из него? К примеру, `print(titles['href'])` выдаст только ссылку, без самого элемента.

Comment: Прошу прощения за такой долгий ответ. Это мне и надо было, Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Без проблем, рад был помочь!